# Iterated class binding to spans

Tags: vue.js

I have 10 black stars and want to paint them with an iteration. I painted them through class binding 10 different spans but I want only one span (max two) for these instead 10.

For example if my "star" data equals to 4, I want 4 painted and 6 unpainted stars.

You should check my pen below. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/kaangokdemir/sbecv2fh/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    painted: 4,
    unpainted: 6
  }
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/pro.min.css" media="all">


<div id="app">
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>0}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>1}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>2}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>3}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>4}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>5}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>6}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>7}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>8}"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-star" :class="{checked: painted>9}"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 variations. All are using `v-for` with a range: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

The first just assumes there are always 10 stars.

The second and third show two different ways of combining `painted` and `unpainted`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    painted: 4,
    unpainted: 16
  }
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: orange;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/pro.min.css" media="all">


<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <span
      v-for="index in 10"
      class="fa fa-star"
      :class="{checked: painted >= index}"
    ></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span
      v-for="index in painted + unpainted"
      class="fa fa-star"
      :class="{checked: painted >= index}"
    ></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span
      v-for="index in painted"
      class="fa fa-star checked"
    ></span>
    <span
      v-for="index in unpainted"
      class="fa fa-star"
    ></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I've added a `row` class on the wrapper. This turns on flex-box to get consistent horizontal spacing between the stars.

Comment: Yea but if unpainted gives me the unpainted ones, It will be awesome.

Comment: @KaanGokdemir I don't understand. Are you saying that there aren't necessarily 10 stars?

Comment: Yes but this 10 stars coming from painted + unpainted. So if unpainted become 8, there should be 12 stars with 4 painted and 8 unpainted instead.

Comment: @KaanGokdemir I have updated my answer accordingly.